# is it possible to make doxygen to merge member groups

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am using doxygen to document C++ code. Let's say I have two classes: class Base and class Derived derived from Base. I have a member group with named Foo in both Base and Derived. Is it possible to make doxygen to show a single group named Foo in documentation for class Derived instead of having two identically named groups as I observe now?

Comment: Your are using `INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB` to show members of bases in the documentation of derived classes, right?

Comment: @pmr yes I do. I do not see any other relevant options

Comment: After some experimentation I don't think it is possible. You might want to file a feature request in the bugtracker.

Answer (score 2):

I patched a checkout of doxygen to do this.  The patch is below.  I haven't noticed any ill effects in the generated documentation.  The downside of the implementation is that it is an O(n^2) algorithm where n is the number of member groups.  In my case the number of member groups is small enough that the complexity doesn't bother me.

```
Index: src/util.cpp
===================================================================
--- src/util.cpp    (revision 848)
+++ src/util.cpp    (working copy)
@@ -5759,6 +5759,24 @@
           (*ppMemberGroupSDict)->setAutoDelete(TRUE);
         }
         MemberGroup *mg = (*ppMemberGroupSDict)->find(groupId);
+
+        uint ngrps = (*ppMemberGroupSDict)->count();
+        const char * ghs = info->header;
+        int          gid = groupId;
+        for (uint i=0; i != ngrps; ++i)
+        {
+          MemberGroup *tg = (*ppMemberGroupSDict)->at(i);
+          MemberListIterator oli(*(tg->members()));
+          MemberDef *omd = oli.current();
+          const char * ohs = Doxygen::memGrpInfoDict[omd->getMemberGroupId()]->header;
+          int          oid = tg->groupId();
+          if ( ghs && ohs && strcmp(ghs, ohs) == 0)
+          {
+            mg = tg;
+            break;
+          }
+        }
+
         if (mg==0)
         {
           mg = new MemberGroup(
```

The code works by scanning the groups already in the member group dictionary for a group that has the same name (i.e., header).  If such a group is found then that group is used as the member group for the member being inserted.

Comment: Why don't you ask to include your patch in Doxygen? I think this should be the default behavior, or at least should be optional but anyway included in Doxygen.

Comment: I prepared a patch, but it was submitted as 1.8.4 was released and development moved from svn to git.  doxygen 1.8.4 formats the documentation differently and I wasn't able to reproduce the issue easily in that version.  I haven't had more cycles to put into it in the meantime, but will submit a patch when it's ready.

Comment: If the patch was taken, could you provide the config option to enable it? I've been trying to do this for two hours or so.... If it was not taken, could you state that so I know my quest is a waste of time.

Comment: The patch wasn't taken.  At the time I wasn't able to reproduce the issue with my example with 1.8.4.  I need to revisit the issue as I should update the version of doxygen I use to build my docs, but that's not going to happen before the new year.